# Passing build arguments in test context vscode

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

What is the way to pass extra argument to the test context in VS Code?

It is quite straightforward for task:

```
"args": [
                "build",
                "${workspaceFolder}/src/MySolution.sln",
                "-c",
                "Level1"
            ]
```

It is giving me a task which produce such a command:

```
dotnet build {workspaceFolder}/src/MySolution.sln -c Level1
```

How can I achieve the same for tests?

I am using built in testing feature without any extra extensions. When i am running the tests it is building a project with default build command:

```
dotnet build {workspaceFolder}/src/MySolution.sln /property:GenerateFullPaths=true /consoleloggerparameters:NoSummary
```

I would like to respect that extra -c argument.